# separate the page title from page content

Tags: theming, nodes

I am using {{ page.content }} to print all my page content. It is printing my all content but I want to remove title from this content and print it separately in different div structure (without using  page.content). Currently its taking drupal default structure. Is it possible?

Comment: Page title is a block that can be managed from Blocks layout and you disable it/ remove it from there

Comment: How? from where?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you display the 'Title' field on display/page for custom content type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210617/how-do-you-display-the-title-field-on-display-page-for-custom-content-type)

Answer (score 2):

as @Hodba Khalaf mentioned in comment **Page title is a block** go to ***admin/structure/block*** a block called **Page title** added by core 
[image]

But you can render page content without specific field in twig by using [`without filter`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates#without) for example you can render page content without page title try something like:

```
    {{ page.content|without('bartik_page_title') }}
```

**Note :** in the example above page title block element is `bartik_page_title` because i use bartik theme so it could be different in your case, dump the **page.content** to get the key of your title page.